# Create a dataframe from specific values in OrderedDict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ordereddictionary

I have an OrderedDict like this:

```
OrderedDict([('searchedFolder', {'id': '1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK', 'name': 'Test', 
'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}), ('folderTree', OrderedDict([('id', 
[['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK'], ['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK', 
'1bfMsEMU7zyILW6sLsTkZhjLLrogcWK8P'], ['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK', 
'1jyIXgH7hCOcqdb0ouNsR9EYWsRrjgPC3']]), ('names', ['Test', 'Test1', 'Test2']), ('folders', 
['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK', '1bfMsEMU7zyILW6sLsTkZhjLLrogcWK8P', 
'1jyIXgH7hCOcqdb0ouNsR9EYWsRrjgPC3'])])), ('fileList', [{'files': [{'id': 
'1I0vsHBo8GyWb1Jr30hQflTTZ3eIXpm8x', 'name': 'test1.xlsx'}], 'folderTree': 
['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK']}, {'files': [{'id': '1TEBzg_EH9iG9A3i6oN18ZSElUE1EhwxY', 
'name': 'test2.xlsx'}], 'folderTree': ['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK', 
'1bfMsEMU7zyILW6sLsTkZhjLLrogcWK8P']}, {'files': [{'id': '1jJwFxbKRYRYn4vRzNf62LYL27EfAHSvq', 
'name': 'test3.xlsx'}, {'id': '10ReTrPWGr_inWjj_eahFtBmIYtjthw2s', 'name': 'test4.xlsx'}], 
'folderTree': ['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK', '1jyIXgH7hCOcqdb0ouNsR9EYWsRrjgPC3']}]), 
('totalNumberOfFolders', 3), ('totalNumberOfFiles', 4)])
```

I want to create a dataframe with the file names and id's that looks like this:

```
              id                                      name
0     1I0vsHBo8GyWb1Jr30hQflTTZ3eIXpm8x             test1.xlsx
1     1TEBzg_EH9iG9A3i6oN18ZSElUE1EhwxY             test2.xlsx
2     1jJwFxbKRYRYn4vRzNf62LYL27EfAHSvq             test3.xlsx   
3     10ReTrPWGr_inWjj_eahFtBmIYtjthw2s             test4.xlsx
```

The file names are just random for testing purposes and I also have other files not just excel (.png, .jpg, .doc etc..)

First I tried to create a dataframe and  then extract these values using:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(Ordereddict) or df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Ordereddict)
```

but I was getting this error:

```
ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ONE WAY:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(ord_dict['fileList'], record_path=['files'])
```

OR:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ord_dict['fileList'])['files'].explode().apply(pd.Series)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
                                  id        name
0  1I0vsHBo8GyWb1Jr30hQflTTZ3eIXpm8x  test1.xlsx
1  1TEBzg_EH9iG9A3i6oN18ZSElUE1EhwxY  test2.xlsx
2  1jJwFxbKRYRYn4vRzNf62LYL27EfAHSvq  test3.xlsx
2  10ReTrPWGr_inWjj_eahFtBmIYtjthw2s  test4.xlsx
```

Complete code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
ord_dict = OrderedDict([('searchedFolder', {'id': '1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK', 'name': 'Test', 
'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}), ('folderTree', OrderedDict([('id', 
[['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK'], ['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK', 
'1bfMsEMU7zyILW6sLsTkZhjLLrogcWK8P'], ['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK', 
'1jyIXgH7hCOcqdb0ouNsR9EYWsRrjgPC3']]), ('names', ['Test', 'Test1', 'Test2']), ('folders', 
['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK', '1bfMsEMU7zyILW6sLsTkZhjLLrogcWK8P', 
'1jyIXgH7hCOcqdb0ouNsR9EYWsRrjgPC3'])])), ('fileList', [{'files': [{'id': 
'1I0vsHBo8GyWb1Jr30hQflTTZ3eIXpm8x', 'name': 'test1.xlsx'}], 'folderTree': 
['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK']}, {'files': [{'id': '1TEBzg_EH9iG9A3i6oN18ZSElUE1EhwxY', 
'name': 'test2.xlsx'}], 'folderTree': ['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK', 
'1bfMsEMU7zyILW6sLsTkZhjLLrogcWK8P']}, {'files': [{'id': '1jJwFxbKRYRYn4vRzNf62LYL27EfAHSvq', 
'name': 'test3.xlsx'}, {'id': '10ReTrPWGr_inWjj_eahFtBmIYtjthw2s', 'name': 'test4.xlsx'}], 
'folderTree': ['1uTjm6QEx7No09bgTX984lxmwMSfv2sYK', '1jyIXgH7hCOcqdb0ouNsR9EYWsRrjgPC3']}]), 
('totalNumberOfFolders', 3), ('totalNumberOfFiles', 4)])

df = pd.json_normalize(ord_dict['fileList'], record_path=['files'])
```